# Creating a signed transaction USDT / matic

Tags: web3js, polygon, usdt

I want to create a signed transaction that sends USDT to two different receivers, using MATIC. I have a polygon node working (from Alchemy), but I am currently stuck on this error:

```
Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance
```

But my account has 2 USDT and 0.9901 MATIC, so I do not understand why I get this error.

I am using the web3 sdk, and currently just doing a simple POC. I am new to ETH and contracts, I have only been working on Doge/BTC earlier so this is a new new to me.

My test code (which I currently am trying to get to work with 1 receiver for simplification):

```js
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

const privateKey = 'XXXXXXXX';
const usdtContractAddress = '0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f';


const options = {
  keepAlive: true,
  withCredentials: false,
  timeout: 20000
  ]
};

//using a local proxy with key, this works fine.
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
  'http://localhost:8110/polygon/rpc',
  options,
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const createSignedTransactionForNewContract = async (receiver1, amount1, receiver2, amount2, contractAddress) => {
  const senderAddress = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;
  console.log('sender address: '+senderAddress);

  // Get the nonce
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress, 'latest');
  let contractAbi = '';
  try {
    contractAbi = [
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_from",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "version",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_owner",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "balance",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          },
          {
            "name": "_extraData",
            "type": "bytes"
          }
        ],
        "name": "approveAndCall",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_owner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "remaining",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_initialAmount",
            "type": "uint256"
          },
          {
            "name": "_tokenName",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "_decimalUnits",
            "type": "uint8"
          },
          {
            "name": "_tokenSymbol",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "type": "constructor"
      },
      {
        "payable": false,
        "type": "fallback"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_from",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_owner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
      },
    ];

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

    // Example: Encode a transaction to transfer USDT to two receivers
    //const transferUSDTData = contract.methods.transfer(receiver1, amount1, receiver2, amount2).encodeABI();
    const transferUSDTData = contract.methods.transfer(receiver1, amount1).encodeABI();


    let gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

    console.log('Gas price: '+gasPrice);

    // Create the transaction object
    const txObject = {
      from: senderAddress,
      to: contractAddress,
      nonce: nonce,
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
      data: transferUSDTData
    };

    // Sign the transaction
    const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);

    return signedTransaction.rawTransaction;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error for further handling if needed
  }
};

let amountInDecimal = 0.01;

// Example usage
const receiver1 = '0xC9471eE243627273Df31Ea8d8b95653CDc97f9D4';
const amount1 = web3.utils.toWei(amountInDecimal.toString(), 'ether');
const receiver2 = '0xCE7F9CC7bf2DC89d5968619303C0484f25eba352';
const amount2 = web3.utils.toWei(0.001, 'ether');

createSignedTransactionForNewContract(receiver1, amount1, receiver2, amount2,usdtContractAddress)
  .then(rawTransaction => {
    console.log('Signed Transaction:', rawTransaction);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: First think that pops up is that ETH is using 18 decimals, USDT just 6. You might need to fix it when calling `web3.utils.toWei(XYZ, 'ether')`, that's why you are exceeding the balance.
Secondly, are you approving the sender before executing the signed transaction?

Comment: Great, thanks! It was the decimals that was the issue, when converting that manually it worked!